# backspace beep on Debian Sid on Latitude e5479

Tags: debian, motherboard, beep-code

I've installed Debian Stable and then upgraded to Sid on a Latitude e5479. It has no desktop environment. The problem is the backspace beep does not work. It's an important feature of this installation as the user is blind and relies on that functionality. The same installation on a previous laptop had the backspace beep as default.

I can't specifically find any information on the Latitude to verify it does, in fact, have a PC speaker. I assume that it is still pretty common to most motherboards.

I've installed beep from apt and followed the instructions from the Github page, but nothing is happening. It shows the permissions correctly, but I can not get any result when hitting control-G or tab-complete.

Any insights into this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any sound happen at BIOS/POST or interrupt? Verify the pcspeaker isn't disabled there? What happens when you just run `beep` at the cli?

Comment: default user may need to be in "sound" or "audio" groups? (`usermod -a -G sound $user`)